# How to add parameter to url in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi am developing web application with javascript. I have one url to be clicked. Using query string i am getting params and i am trying to bind it to url as below.

```js
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
                if (!url) url = window.location.href;
                name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
                var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
                    results = regex.exec(url);
                if (!results) return null;
                if (!results[2]) return '';
                return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
            }
            var foo = getParameterByName('guid');
            alert(foo);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />  
    <title>ScannerView</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <iframe src="http://Scanner.aufytech.com/C3CKYC Scanner.xbap?param1=foo" width="1000" height="600" scrolling="auto"></iframe>      
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My foo variable contains required values. But when i append p?param1=foo it gives me empty value! May i know is there any way to fix this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `getParameterByName` expects `url` as parameter `function getParameterByName(name, url){}`, though `url` is not passed to `getParameterByName` call at `var foo = getParameterByName('guid')`. What is expected result?

Comment: How is `"guid"` related to URL set at `<iframe>` `.src`?

Answer (score 0):

very simple:

```
history.pushState({}, "title", "?page=1");
```

url from `test.com`
change to `test.com/?page=1`

browser support

```
Feature     Chrome  Edge    Firefox (Gecko) IE  Opera   Safari
pushState   5       (Yes)   4.0 (2.0)       10  11.50   5.0
```